# How to take max between two values in presto?

Tags: sql, presto

I have the following query:

```
select id, table1.date1, table2.date2, table1.name
from table1
join table2 using (id)
```

I want also to have another column with `MAX(table1.date1, table2.date2)` but I don't find the proper syntax for that. I don't want MAX to go over all rows in table and take MAX() I want it to select max from the two values specified in the row.

Example:

```
id  date1       date2    name    max
1 2020-01-01 2020-04-01   A    2020-04-01
2 2019-02-01 2020-01-03   B    2020-01-03
3 2019-02-01    null      c    2019-02-01
```

I can't also do group by because I don't want to group anything here.
It's more similar to `coalesce`  give a function list of values and choose the max value from it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`greatest()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/comparison.html#greatest):

```
select id, t1.date1, t2.date2, t1.name,
       greatest(t1.date1, t2.date2)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     using (id);
```

Note that `greatest()` returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`.  So, if you have `NULL` values, you will need special care.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it

```
select id, table1.date1, table2.date2, table1.name,
case when table1.date1 > table1.date2 then table1.date1 else table1.date2 end as max_date
from table1
join table2 using (id)
```

Comment: yeah that will work I know but what if I have list of 10 dates?

Comment: continue case when with your condition